# iOS UIImagePickerController has white squares instead of icons

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the camera for my app but when i start it, the camera shows up like in the image below.

[image]

This is the code I use to start the camera app:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Why are the camera icons all white?

Comment: Seems strange to me, can you create a small project that has the problem and then link to it so we can get a better understanding of what is going on in the rest of the project?